# Descubrir gateway de red ip de una columna

Tags: python, lista, pandas, redes, ip

Hola tengo un dataframe donde en una columna 'Red' necesito descubrir el primer host de cada red y presentarlo en una nueva columna, ejemplo:

```
    VLAN    Admin   Red 
   VLAN1732 UP  10.101.57.149/28    
   VLAN1733 UP  10.101.57.165/28    
   VLAN1744 UP  10.209.240.5/28 
   VLAN1745 UP  10.209.240.21/28
```

Necesito llegar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya gracias, saludos...

Comment: ¿Y cual sería el problema? O sea, ¿en que topas? ¿cual es la dificultad?

Comment: @Candid Moe, no se cómo resolver una red con python que librería existe que pueda descubrir los host disponible de una red dada, como mí ejemplo donde la columna gw son el primer host de cada red, necesito poder llegar a eso justamente,  gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una dirección IP como 10.101.57.149 está compuesta de dos partes: dirección de subred y host.

La subred se obtiene realizan un `and` bit a bit entre la IP y la máscara de subred. En una IP como "10.101.57.149/28", la máscara contiene los primeros 28 bits en 1, seguido de 4 bits en cero (hasta completar 32 bits).

Para la IP "10.101.57.149/28", la operación da "10.101.57.144", que es un número con los cuatro últimos bits en 0. El GW es el primer host, que se obtiene sumando uno al número de red.

Todo esta aritmética se puede obviar recurriendo a la librería especializada `ipaddress`, que hace toda clase de operaciones con direcciones IP y subredes.

La función `IPv4Network` recibe una cadena en formato "ip/mascara" y devuelve un objeto con información sobre la subred. El parámetro `strict=False` nos permite entregar direcciones IP que no son propiamente direcciones de subred, si no de host dentro de la subred.

Entre otros datos, el objeto nos ofrece los siguientes atributos:

- La subred propiamente tal.
- La lista de hosts validos dentro de la subred, ordenados. El primero sería el gateway.

**Código**

```
import ipaddress

def get_gw(network):
    net = ipaddress.IPv4Network(network, strict=False)
    return net.network_address, [x for x in net.hosts()][0]
```

**Demo**

```
redes = ["10.101.57.149/28",
        "10.101.57.165/28",
        "10.209.240.5/28",
        "10.209.240.21/28"]

for red in redes:
    net, gw = get_gw(red)
    print(f"Red/mask {red} : Red {net}, GW {gw}")
```

produce:

```
Red/mask 10.101.57.149/28 : Red 10.101.57.144, GW 10.101.57.145
Red/mask 10.101.57.165/28 : Red 10.101.57.160, GW 10.101.57.161
Red/mask 10.209.240.5/28 : Red 10.209.240.0, GW 10.209.240.1
Red/mask 10.209.240.21/28 : Red 10.209.240.16, GW 10.209.240.17
```

Comment: excelente @Candid Moe muchas gracias era lo que necesitaba.. saludos